# mercurial hg clone a repo from a server connected through another server

Tags: ssh, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgrc

I have three machines

```
local (windows)
serverA (linux) with username as userA
serverB (linux) with username as userB
```

I want to clone a hg repository in `serverB` to my local machine using TortoiseHg for windows. The machine `serverB` can be `ssh`ed only though `serverA`. So in winScp/PuTTY I use tunneling option to connect to `serverB` through `serverA`. But how do I do it in TortoiseHg?

Obviously I cannot use `hg clone ssh://userB@serverB://<path to repo>`. But is there a way to use multiple ssh commands`. I tried the below approach and it did not work:

`$cat ~/.ssh/config`

```
host serverB.example.com serverB
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/ssh serverA.example.com /usr/bin/nc %h %p
```

Comment: What you mean by "did not work"? Did you try also the `-w` way of proxy command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options:

1. You can forward the `ssh` port on `serverA`, in your `.ssh/config` add something like:

   ```
   host serverBtunnel
      LocalForward    2222 serverB.example.com:22
   ```

   Then start the tunnel (on `serverA`) with:

   ```
   ssh -N serverBtunnel
   ```

   After this you can clone the repo (from your windows box) using:

   ```
   hg clone ssh://userB@serverA:2222//<path to repo>
   ```
2. Create the tunnel directly from `Putty` (see [here](http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html) for more details). Basically:

   - You will define and add the tunnel to `serverB`:
     [image: defineTunnel]
   - Then create the session to `serverA` (that will have the tunnel defined):
     [image]
   - This way, on your windows box (assuming that the above session is started), you will be able to clone the repo, using:

     ```
     hg clone ssh://userB@localhost:2222//<path to repo>
     ```

Comment: my local machine windows.

Comment: Bad owner or permissions on `~/.ssh/config`. Do I need to set permissions on this file

Comment: The permissions on `.ssh` directory should be `700` and for `config` you should use `640`.

Comment: I think that the putty alternative, that I added, is simpler and you don't need to log to `serverA` anymore. But on the first option, to start that tunnel on `serverA`, you will use `ssh -N userA@serverBtunnel `

Comment: UserA@serverBtunnel? Shouldn't it be userB@serverBtunnel?

Comment: No, when using `serverBtunnel` you need to use the `userA`, because on `serverA`  we are creating the tunnel.

Comment: I have no idea why the first option is not working for me. But the configuration via PuTTY works just fine. Thanks